# Parsley's EXCLUDED not recognizing :last

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I am trying to make Parlsley validate all the rows in the table except the last one, and it seems to ignore me )

```
$('form').parsley({
            excluded: 'tr:last'
        }).validate();
```

Here's the [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1fq8uyzf/)

Any ideas ?

Comment: I found this link that may help you: https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/664

Comment: A little bit more respect for `parsley` would be appreciated. No idea where you get the idea that `parsley` has "numerous bugs". Of the 1100 issues, 40 are opened, most are feature requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`excluded` works by filtering your inputs, i.e:

```
$yourForm.find(inputs).not(excluded)`
```

It does not "redo" the search from the form level, i.e. it **does not** do:

```
$yourForm.find(inputs).not($yourForm.find(excluded))  # *Not* the way Parsley treats `excluded`
```

Your `excluded` selector is thus ineffective.

Comment: I am ready to publicly apologise if you prove this in JSFiddle

Comment: If I prove what exactly?

Comment: I've expanded my answer in hope you will understand what I mean, despite your tone which I continue to feel as arrogant.

Comment: Your answer translates into `$('form').find ('tr:not(:last) input').parsley().validate();` which worked for me indeed. Sorry. I've removed the phrases about bugs